# How do I make my Azure DevOps CI CD pipeline faster?

Tags: azure, continuous-integration, devops

How do I make my Azure DevOps CI CD pipeline faster?

How do I make my Azure DevOps CI CD pipeline faster?

Comment: What exactly is slow? How does your pipeline look like? There is simply not enough information here to help you.